Error: Native module RNFBAppModule not found. Re-check module install, linking, configuration, build and install steps. Trying to use Firebase In expo
Firebase Phone Auth Integration Error in Expo (NOBRIDGE)
Problem
I'm trying to implement Firebase Phone Authentication in my Expo React Native app but getting the following error:
ERROR  Error: Native module RNFBAppModule not found. Re-check module install, linking, configuration, build and install steps.

Environment
Expo SDK:"~52.0.23",

"react": "18.3.1",

"react-native": "0.76.5",

"@react-native-firebase/app": "^21.6.1",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^21.6.1",

Platform: iOS/Android


What I've Tried

Installed Firebase:
npx expo install @react-native-firebase/app

Added Firebase configuration in app.json:
{
"expo": {
"plugins": [
"@react-native-firebase/app"
]
}
}

Set up firebase-config.js with proper credentials


Code
Here's my login screen implementation:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { 
  View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, 
  StyleSheet, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, Keyboard, 
  TouchableWithoutFeedback, Alert
} from 'react-native';
import { Phone, Package, ArrowRight } from 'lucide-react-native';
import { useUser } from './context/UserContext';
import { auth } from '../firebase.config';
import { PhoneAuthProvider, signInWithCredential } from 'firebase/auth';

const LoginScreen = () => {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [otpSent, setOtpSent] = useState(false);
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState(null);
  const { updateUserData } = useUser();

  const handleSendOTP = async () => {
    try {
      const phoneRegex = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
      if (!phoneRegex.test(phoneNumber)) {
        setError('Please enter a valid 10-digit phone number');
        return;
      }

      const formattedPhone = `+91${phoneNumber}`; // Adjust country code
      
      const appVerifier = {
        type: 'recaptcha',
        verify: () => Promise.resolve('dummy-token')
      };

      const verificationId = await PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
        auth,
        formattedPhone,
        appVerifier
      );
      
      setVerificationId(verificationId);
      setOtpSent(true);
      setError('');
      Alert.alert('OTP Sent', 'Please check your phone for the verification code');
    } catch (err) {
      setError('Failed to send OTP. Please try again.');
      console.error('Send OTP error:', err);
    }
  };

  const handleVerifyOTP = async () => {
    try {
      if (otp.length !== 6) {
        setError('Please enter a 6-digit OTP');
        return;
      }

      const credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, otp);
      const userCredential = await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
      
      updateUserData({
        phone: phoneNumber,
        isLoggedIn: true,
        uid: userCredential.user.uid
      });
      
      setError('');
    } catch (err) {
      setError('Invalid OTP. Please try again.');
      console.error('Verify OTP error:', err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView 
          behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
          style={styles.keyboardContainer}
        >
          <View style={styles.header}></View>
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
              <Package color="#FF85A2" size={64} />
              <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>Welcome to Pink Parcel</Text>
              <Text style={styles.subtitleText}>Your premium delivery partner</Text>
            </View>

            {!otpSent ? (
              <View style={styles.inputSection}>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                  <Phone color="#FF85A2" size={24} style={styles.inputIcon} />
                  <TextInput
                    placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
                    placeholderTextColor="#8F90A6"
                    keyboardType="phone-pad"
                    value={phoneNumber}
                    onChangeText={setPhoneNumber}
                    maxLength={10}
                    style={styles.input}
                  />
                </View>

                <TouchableOpacity 
                  style={styles.primaryButton} 
                  onPress={handleSendOTP}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Send OTP</Text>
                  <ArrowRight color="#FFFFFF" size={20} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            ) : (
              <View style={styles.inputSection}>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                  <Package color="#E91E63" size={24} style={styles.inputIcon} />
                  <TextInput
                    placeholder="Enter 6-digit OTP"
                    placeholderTextColor="#8F90A6"
                    keyboardType="number-pad"
                    value={otp}
                    onChangeText={setOtp}
                    maxLength={6}
                    style={styles.input}
                  />
                </View>

                <TouchableOpacity 
                  style={styles.primaryButton}
                  onPress={handleVerifyOTP}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Verify OTP</Text>
                  <ArrowRight color="#FFFFFF" size={20} />
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity 
                  style={styles.secondaryButton}
                  onPress={() => setOtpSent(false)}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.secondaryButtonText}>Change Phone Number</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            )}

            {error ? (
              <Text style={styles.errorText}>{error}</Text>
            ) : null}
          </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF5F8',
  },
  keyboardContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingVertical: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF5F8',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#FFF5F8',
  },
  headerTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '700',
    color: '#2D2D3A',
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
  },
  logoContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginVertical: 40,
  },
  welcomeText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '700',
    color: '#2D2D3A',
    marginTop: 16,
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
  subtitleText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#8F90A6',
  },
  inputSection: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 24,
    padding: 20,
    shadowColor: '#E91E63',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 4 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.08,
    shadowRadius: 12,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#FFE4EC',
    marginBottom: 20,
    paddingVertical: 8,
  },
  inputIcon: {
    marginRight: 12,
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 50,
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#2D2D3A',
  },
  primaryButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#E91E63',
    borderRadius: 16,
    paddingVertical: 14,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    gap: 8,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  secondaryButton: {
    paddingVertical: 14,
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 12,
  },
  secondaryButtonText: {
    color: '#E91E63',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  errorText: {
    color: '#E91E63',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 16,
    fontSize: 14,
  },
});

export default LoginScreen;

Expected Behavior
Firebase Phone Authentication should work in my Expo app.
Actual Behavior
Getting NOBRIDGE error indicating native module is not found.
Can anyone help identify what I'm missing in the setup?
